# How to validate input email in angucomplete-alt?

Tags: angularjs

I use the foloowing library in Angular JS:

https://github.com/ghiden/angucomplete-alt

How to validate autocomplete input on email type? If unvalid to show error?

I tried to use `field-required="true"`, but id does not validate on email:

```
<angucomplete-alt
                              placeholder="<%= t('projects.project_full.invitation.enter_email_title') %>"
                              pause="100"
                              id="ex8b"
                              selected-object="selectedInvitationUsers"
                              local-data="invitable_users"
                              search-fields="fullname,email"
                              title-field="fullname,email"
                              minlength="1"
                              input-name="invite.email"
                              override-suggestions="true"
                              input-changed="inputChangeHandler"
                              field-required="true"
                              input-class="form-control form-control-small"/>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Did you wrap it within a form? https://ghiden.github.io/angucomplete-alt/#example8

Comment: Yes, I wrapped that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change element directive to attribute style such as :

```
<div angucomplete-alt
                              placeholder="<%= t('projects.project_full.invitation.enter_email_title') %>"
                              pause="100"
                              id="ex8b"
                              selected-object="selectedInvitationUsers"
                              local-data="invitable_users"
                              search-fields="fullname,email"
                              title-field="fullname,email"
                              minlength="1"
                              input-name="invite.email"
                              override-suggestions="true"
                              input-changed="inputChangeHandler"
                              field-required="true"
                              input-class="form-control form-control-small"/>
                        </div>
```